# Unable to use the /apprequests endpoint on Facebook Graph API

Tags: node.js, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, passport.js

I'm using passport.js on node to authenticate users. I'm trying to add the ability for users to invite friends to my game. I'm able to query the /invitable_friends endpoint to get a list of friends not using the app, but I can't seem to get /apprequests to work.

I'm attempting to do a post request from the browser based on the [API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/apprequests/).

```
var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+ uid + '/apprequests' +
'?access_token=' + accessToken +
'&message=Invitation' +
'&action_type=INVITE' +
'&ids=' + inviteTokens;
```

Where inviteTokens is a comma separated string of the invite tokens returned from /invitable_friends.

I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid token: \"811513274\".  An ID has already been specified.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500,
    "fbtrace_id": "BrulDCVO+SE"
  }
}
```

The query works if I exclude the ids parameter, but the request is just sent to myself. If I exclude my uid in the endpoint path, I get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: {inviteTokens},
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "AL6Yo+jAwWW"
  }
}
```

Which implies that the endpoint is expecting something else, but the docs use the access token in the [example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.5):

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE',
    to: 'USER_ID, USER_ID, INVITE_TOKEN'
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

I've also tried using the Graph API explorer with the same results.

Hopefully, I provided enough detail here, but let me know if you need anything else. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Facebook doesn't allow invites to be sent directly with POST request. Invites have to go through the frontend dialog in the Javascript SDK, so FB can verify that a user actually wants to send the invite.

Comment: Hi Brian, I have this exact same problem (on iOS). Where did you get the info you posted above (Facebook design decision of forcing the frontend dialog)?

Comment: Hmm, I can't quite remember, maybe a blog post? I think they were having issues with apps sending malicious programmatic invites that we're initiated or approved by the user. By forcing the app to use their frontend dialog they could ensure that users approved the invites. Not quite sure it translates over to iOS, though.

Comment: Thanks! It's the same on iOS.